# My JS is not working with my html/css. Not sure why. (Console error 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a content slider, and am having difficulties with it functioning appropriately. Specifically when testing locally the aspect that is not working is: (When you click the arrows left or right the current-slide fades out and fades back in but the slide content does not switch to the next block of content.)

**Here is my HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>PLACEHOLDER</title>

<meta name"keywords" content="PLACEHOLDER" />

<meta name"description" content="PLACEHOLDER" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="slider">

  <div class="slide active-slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
          <h1 id="welcome">FIRST SLIDE HEADER</h1>
          <div id="img1">
            <img src="######.png" width="450" height="250" />
          </div>
          <div id="intro">
            <p>FIRST SLIDE CONTENT</p </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="slide slide-feature">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h1>Slide2</h1>
              <p>Slide 2 stuff.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Slide 3</h1>
              <h2>Slide3</h2>
              <p>Slide3 content</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Slide 4</h1>
              <p>slide 4 content</p>


            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
        <img src="ARROW LEFT IMAGE">
      </a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
        <img src="ARROW RIGHT IMAGE">
      </a>
    </div>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```js
var main = function () {
$('.arrow-next').click(function () {
   var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
   var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
       var nextDot = currentDot.next()

   if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
       nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
       nextDot = $('.dot').first();
   }
currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
   
   currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
   nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
});
$('.arrow-prev').click(function()
{
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
       var prevDot = currentDot.prev()
    
    if(prevSlide.length == 0)
    {
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();

    }
    
     currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
   prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
});

};


$(document).ready(main);
```

**HERE IS MY CSS**(Just to tie it all together):

```css
.slider {
 position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 470px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-top: -8%;
}

.slide {
  background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slide-copy h1 {
  color: #363636;  
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slide-copy h2 {
  color: #b7b7b7;
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slide-copy p {
  color: #959595;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.slide-img {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ac.png');
  height: 470px;
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.slide-feature a {
  display: block;
  color: #6fc5e0;
  
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 20px;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
margin-top: 30%;
}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #363636;
}
```

NOTE: I only put the sections of html/js/css that matter for this case. And I used placeholders for some text and images. On my local machine those placeholders are replaced with correct content.

Comment: Include jquery library.

Comment: as @Manwal suggested you need to include jquery library.

Comment: Updated my  html snippet. I had the jquery library just didnt include in snippet. The problem was since I was working locally I was missing the "html" portion. It works now the slides change ut the content stays the same...hmmm must be doing something else wrong

Comment: Wrap jquery code with `$(document).ready(function(){/*yourcode */  })`. in your jquery code.

Comment: I have it at the end as $(document).ready(main);

Comment: Moving it to the beggining didnt work. In fact made it not work entirely lol weird. Right now it works and I see the slide fades out and fades back in, its just the actual slide content doesnt change

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. Been frustrated trying to figure this out for the last couple days.

Comment: i am working on a fiddle for your issue. will post it when m done.

Comment: you're most welcome @IlyaShekhtman :) here's the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gbncj1f7/ please check it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. I am going to start incorporating in to my local code and see if it works. What did the problem end up being?

Comment: it was the HTML. the javascript code works fine. just replace this html with yours. the div with the class active-slide was the parent for all the other slides so the javascript code was not able to find the next slide

Comment: i'll post this as a solution. please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Ah I see I was missing two </div>s lol hmm.

Comment: So its working now. BUT now my css for the slider-nav is not behaving properly. After adding those two </div> it moved the slider-nav all the way to the bottom of the page. I had positioned it to be directly under the slide content box.

Comment: lso where is that picture coming from on slide 2? Lol its not in my html at all....very confused about that

Comment: I will definitely upvote and mark as answer. I appreciate your help thus far!!

Comment: Found where the image was coming from. It was in css lol

Comment: yeah @IlyaShekhtman. at first even I was wondering where the pic was coming from. then found out it was your css ;). I've posted my solution. please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: let me see if i can do anything with the position of the `slider-nav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the HTML closely, you'll see that the slider div's are not positioned properly. all the other div's with the class `'.slide'` are enclosed inside `<div class="slide active-slide">` whereas they should be independent of each other. 
the javascript code is not able to find the `next()` slide since they're all contained in one single **parent** which is the `'active-slide'`

you need to update your HTML to the following

```
<div class="slider">

    <div class="slide active-slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                    <h1 id="welcome">FIRST SLIDE HEADER</h1>
                    <div id="img1">
                        <img src="######.png" width="450" height="250" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="intro">
                        <p>FIRST SLIDE CONTENT</p </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide-feature">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Slide2</h1>
                    <p>Slide 2 stuff.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
                    <h2>Slide3</h2>
                    <p>Slide3 content</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                    <h1>Slide 4</h1>
                    <p>slide 4 content</p>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
        <img src="ARROW LEFT IMAGE">
    </a>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
        <img src="ARROW RIGHT IMAGE">
    </a>
</div>
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gbncj1f7/)** for the same. hope this helps

Comment: So its working now. BUT now my css for the slider-nav is not behaving properly. After adding those two </div> it moved the slider-nav all the way to the bottom of the page. I had positioned it to be directly under the slide content box. I appreciate all your help thus far and will definitely upvote and accept as answer!!

Comment: let me check the position.

Comment: I was able to fix the positioning by getting rid of the margin I had originally set up for the slider-nav class.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Ah one issue is still there....For slide 2 all the palceholder stuff gets moved to the top of the page instead of how slides 1 3 and 4 display in the content block. Wondering why slide 2 does that. Localy for me it ends up going to my banner in the content block shows up as empty.

Comment: Nvm fixed that too. it had the wrong class somehow. Sheesh I musta been doing this late -_- Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: if you compare slide 1 with the others you'll see that the first slide has a header div and an image div with the intro. any reason why the others are different?

Comment: Yeah each slide will have different types of information. I was able to change the class of slide 2 to the same class as slide 3 and 4 and that fixed it. Also the fact that I dont have all of the content ready is the biggest reason why there is no image div on the other slides :D Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the jQuery library from here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I didn't post the entire html.
Here is the rest.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>PLACEHOLDFER</title>

<meta name"keywords" content="PLACEHOLDER"" />

<meta name"description" content="PLACEHOLDER" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
</head>

<body>

Comment: Okay, try putting your jquery reference before your script code.

Comment: Ah, you just need to change `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`
to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Ok adding the "http" worked...du...however the slides don't change I can tell the slide changes but it keeps the same content. O.o I must be doing something else wrong.  Thanks for help thus far

Comment: No problem.

At a glance it looks like the "slide" elements are not nested correctly, so you have them inside each other instead of after each other.

But that's just a guess :) good luck.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought originally but looking at it over and over it seems like they are nested alright O.o maybe Im just not seeing something lol. Arrgh

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if you haven't included jquery file or you are getting conflicts in jquery.

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Add following in Head section of your code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updated my html snippet. I had the jquery library just didnt include in snippet. The problem was since I was working locally I was missing the "html" portion. It works now the slides change ut the content stays the same...hmmm must be doing something else wrong